# How to return a ajax response in c#?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

I am new to AJAX and C#, So i am trying how to work them together. I am building a web application and I am invoking a method from c# in my ajax function and if everything works fine then I want to receive the success message back to my c# class. How can I do that?
This is my ajax method

```
<script type="text/javascript">


 Hello();
    function Hello() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Dtata.aspx/Hello",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result) {
                response(result.d);
            },
            error: function (result) {
                alert('There is a problem processing your request');
            }
        });
    }


</script>

  //Basically I want to know the success/failure value from the Ajax call and print it back to my console.

   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    }

    [WebMethod]
    public static string Hello(string name)
    {
        return name;
    }
```

Comment: i think you missed to pass the string name in your ajax call ..somthing like:  $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Dtata.aspx/Hello",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json", data:{name:'hello'}
            success: function (result) {
                response(result.d);
            },
            error: function (result) {
                alert('There is a problem processing your request');
            }
        });

Comment: You are trying to build a circular request-response. The response sent by the C# web method will be there in the AJAX success. You are trying to resend this to the server again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried to pass also the data in your ajax call? (string name) .. cause your back end service (webMethod) have it in its method param...something like:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">




        Hello();
            function Hello() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Dtata.aspx/Hello",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data:{name:'hello'},
                    success: function (result) {
                        response(result.d);
                        Counter() //<-- CALL OTHER AJAX METHOD TO INCREASE COUNTER ON BACK END
                    },
                    error: function (result) {
                        alert('There is a problem processing your request');
                    }
                });
            }


 function Counter() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Dtata.aspx/Counter",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",

                    success: function (result) {
                        console.log(result.d);
                    },
                    error: function (result) {
                        alert('There is a problem processing your request');
                    }
                });
            }


        </script>

          //Basically I want to know the success/failure value from the Ajax call and print it back to my console.
         private int _counter;
           protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {


            }

            [WebMethod]
            public static string Hello(string name)
            {
                return name;
            }



             [WebMethod]
                public static int Counter()
                {
                    this._counter = this._counter +1;
                    return this._counter
                }
```

Comment: :- Thank you. But how do I print the success/failure response from the ajax call back to my c# class?

Comment: sorry..don't understand exactly what you want to do .. print the response? ... or send back it to the back end to other WebMethod?

Comment: :- So, my ultimate goal is that I have a counter in my c# class. The counter will be incremented every time the data is passed from my c# to ajax method and the method returns a "success" response. The counter will only increment if the response is success. So, that's why I have to find a way to read the ajax response so that I can increment my counter value in my c# class.

Comment: so you create anther jquery ajax function which call the other webmethod (where you increase the counter) and call the js function in the success of the Hello() function

Answer (score 0):

You missed data in ajax call:

```
var counter=0;
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "Dtata.aspx/Hello",
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     dataType: "json",
     data:{name:"test"}
     success: function (result) {
           //result is response from c#. you can do your trick here
           alert(result.d);
           if(result.d=="success"){
               counter++;
           }
     },
     error: function (result) {
          alert('There is a problem processing your request');
     }
 });
```

Comment: :- How do  I send the counter value back to my c# class because the counter value will be sent as an array index which then does the rest of the work. So, I have to find a way to send the counter value back to the c# class.

Comment: You can call another ajax method to sent counter value to c# class

Comment: :- Kindly can you show me how to do that because at this point I am really lost and confused.